# My Google Calendar will be listed in Google Search?

Tags: privacy, calendar, google-search, google-calendar

To subscribe a Google Calendar e.g. in the Mac Calendar App, you have to create a public link to that Google Calendar.

The link obviously has to be publicly available, since you subscribe without a password.

Google claims however, that my calendar WILL appear in the Google Search.

I can not believe that?! Is this really the case? Why would Google list my calendar in the search?

[Proof in Google Help Center](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37083#zippy=%2Cstop-sharing-your-calendar-publicly%2Cmark-your-calendar-as-public) (link checked on October 14 2021 at 07:08 UTC).

It states during the animation (try it yourself in your Google Calendar if you wish):

> "Making your calendar public will make all events visible to the world, including via Google search."